# Compute cohomology of flat fiber bundles - does this always work?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, fibre-bundles

Edit: This has been answered in this thread [Are there compact flat fiber bundles with "truly" infinite structure group?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282282/are-there-compact-flat-fiber-bundles-with-truly-infinite-structure-group).

**Setting**

Let $p: E \rightarrow B$ be a flat fiber bundle with fiber $F$ where $E$, $B$, $F$ are compact, smooth manifolds. Then $E$ has the form of a twisted product

$E \cong \widetilde{B} \times_{\pi_{1}} F$,

where $\widetilde{B}$ is the universal cover of $B$, $\pi_{1}$ is the fundamental group of $B$ and $F$ carries a $\pi_{1}$-action.

We consider cohomology with field coefficients of characteristic zero or not dividing the order of $\pi_1$. (as pointed out by Neil Strickland)

Since we want to compute cohomology and perhaps characteristic classes, we are only concerned with fiber bundles up to fiber preserving homotopy equivalences.

**Background**

$\pi_{1}$ finite would be very convenient, for instance then we'd have $$H^*(E) = H^*(\widetilde{B} \times F)^{\pi_{1}} = (H^*(\widetilde{B}) \times H^*(F))^{\pi_{1}}. $$ (Since then $\widetilde{B} \times F$ is compact and the diagonal action is free.) This product structure on the cohomology of $E$ can be very useful.

Sadly, $\pi_{1}$ is often infinite. However, sometimes we can still reduce the structure group to a finite one. If, for instance, there is a triangulation on $F$ such that the $\pi_{1}$-action on $F$ is simplicial, we can do the following:

The group action is in this case a group homomorphism $$ \phi: \pi_1 \rightarrow \{\text{Permutations of Vertices} \}, $$ 
where the right hand side is finite because $F$ is compact. In particular $G:= \pi_1/ker(\phi) $ is finite. We have $$ E \cong (\widetilde{B}/ker(\phi)) \times_{G} F $$
and thus reduced our structure group to a finite one. The diagonal action is still free and $\widetilde{B}/ker(\phi) \times F$ is compact, so we get $$H^*(E) = H^*(\widetilde{B}/ker(\phi) \times F)^{G} = (H^*(\widetilde{B}/ker(\phi)) \times H^*(F))^{G}. $$

**Question**

Are there compact flat fiber bundles where we cannot do this trick to compute cohomology? I am looking for an explicit example.

**Related**

In this post [simplicial structure on a flat fiber bundle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281140/simplicial-structure-on-a-flat-fiber-bundle) I learned, that we can always replace $F$ by a simplicial complex (roughly $F \times E\pi_1$) but loose compactness. (So the above trick does not work with this.)

Here [Equivalence of Flat Fiber Bundles vs Equivalence of Group Actions on the Fiber](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281963/equivalence-of-flat-fiber-bundles-vs-equivalence-of-group-actions-on-the-fiber) we are looking into what $\pi_{1}$-actions on $F$ result in equivalent fiber bundles. (No answers as of yet though.)

Comment: could you fix the typo in the title?

Comment: For $H^*(E)=H^*(\widetilde{B}\times F)^{\pi_1}$ you need the the field of coefficients to have characteristic zero, or characteristic not dividing the order of $\pi_1$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}$ act on $S^1$ by an irrational rotation: this defines a flat fibre bundle $S^1 \to E \to S^1$. As $\mathbb{Z}$ is a free group this action can be deformed to the trivial action, and so this fibre bundle is isomorphic to the trivial bundle (as a non-flat fibre bundle).

There is clearly no $G$-invariant triangulation of $S^1$. If you try to interpret your formula nonetheless you get $(H^*(\mathbb{R}) \otimes H^*(S^1))^G \cong H^*(S^1)$ which is too small.

Comment: But I can replace this first by the isomoprhic trivial bundle. My formula then just replaces the universal covering $\mathbb{R}$ by the trivial covering $S^1$ and everything works. I meant a counterexample that is not homotopy equivalent to something where it works.