# Are there compact flat fiber bundles with "truly" infinite structure group?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology

Let $p: E \rightarrow B$ be a flat fiber bundle with fiber $F$ where $E$, $B$, $F$ are compact, smooth manifolds.

I am looking for a counterexample for the following statement:

$E \cong \widetilde{B} \times_G F'$, where $G$ is a finite quotient of $\pi_1(B)$ acting on a compact smooth manifold $F'$ and $\widetilde{B}$ is the cover of $B$ associated to that quotient. "$\cong$" stands for a) fiberwise diffeomorphic, b) fiberwise homotopy equivalent.

**Related**

This is one aspect of this question [Compute cohomology of flat fiber bundles - does this always work?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282220/compute-cohomology-of-flat-fiber-bundles-does-this-always-work), more precisely formulated.

Comment: If your monodromy representation has values in $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbf C)$ then your statement is true, according to [Deligne and Sullivan](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~dennis/publications/PDF/DS-pub-0028.pdf).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any finitely presented group occurs as the fundamental group of a smooth compact manifold, so the question reduces to whether we can find a finitely presented group $\pi$ acting on a smooth compact manifold $F$ which does not factor through a finite quotient up to homotopy. In turn, it's enough to find an action whose induced action on the homology groups of $F$ doesn't factor through a finite quotient.

An easy example that comes to mind is $\pi = GL_2(\mathbb{Z}), F = T^2$, since here the action on homology $H_1(T^2)$ is even faithful. Any infinite subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ will do as well, including the copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by any element of infinite order, and so we can get $3$-manifold examples which are $T^2$-bundles over $S^1$ by taking mapping tori.

Comment: Concretely, take $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and form the mapping torus, as Qiaochu  suggested, and compute its fundamental group. It is isomorphic to $N(3,\mathbf Z)$ -- the uppertriangular matrices with integer coefficients. Then show that this group does not contain a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbf Z^3$.

Comment: Right, this 3-manifold is concretely the Heisenberg manifold $H_3(\mathbb{R})/H_3(\mathbb{Z})$.